# Primefaces pickList not updated after submit

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have following code which according to the selection on the selectOneMenu component, it updates the entries in the pickList (in the backend *loadPickList*) and updates the picklist on client side:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="someId" value="#{handler.selection}"
    required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" label="SomeLabel">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{handler.loadPickList}"
        update="pickList" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="SomeLabel" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{handler.myList}" var="listEntry"
        itemValue="#{listEntry}" itemLabel="SomeLabel" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{handler.myPickList}"
    var="entry" itemLabel="SomeLabel" itemValue="#{entry}"
    converter="myConverter">
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Source</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Target</f:facet>
</p:pickList>
```

Everything works as expected. Values in the pickList are updated every time a new selection is made in the selectOneMenu.

The problem is when i submit once the form through a commandButton and a validation is triggered. Then, after choosing another entry from the selectOneMenu my pickList does not get update.

**Note** : The loadPickList is called even after the submition of the form and the pickList is populated in the backend, but i do not see the getter of the pickList being called again.

I tried to add an update="@form" in the submit button, but did no see any difference.

Comment: Hi, please post a [mcve] as requested in [ask]. Otherwise we'd start guessing or asking all kinds of things which would not be needed if you post an mcve. And please post PF version info and JSF impl/version

Comment: did you managed to solved?